# How do I create a cart percentage discount with a coupon code?

Tags: magento2.2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, percentage

I'm trying to create a 25% discount code for the whole cart, not just for one product. Is this possible? I'm pretty new to Magento and the only rules I find is either a percentage for one product or for the whole cart, but then it's accessible even without a code.

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a cart price rule for this. It will do the job.

Comment: But when I create a cart price rule it only gives me a discount on one product in the cart, and when I try to create a rule under catalog price rules the discount is applied without a code. I want the discount to be 25% off for the whole cart and used with a coupon code.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer this link.
**

> https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-coupons-code-in-magento-2/

**
if you are on magento 2